# Attach a file to a list item using CSOM will raise the following error "The file format or file extension is not valid"

Tags: development, csom

I have the following code to attach a file to a list item:-

```
   context.Load(context.Site);
   context.ExecuteQuery();
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File fs = context.Site.RootWeb.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(context.Site.ServerRelativeUrl + "/RiskAssessmentTemplate/Risk%20Assesment.xlsx");
   context.Load(fs);
   context.ExecuteQuery();
   var attInfo = new AttachmentCreationInformation();
   attInfo.FileName = fs.Name;
   var data = fs.OpenBinaryStream();
   context.Load(fs);
   context.ExecuteQuery();
   using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                            data.Value.CopyTo(ms);
                            attInfo.ContentStream = ms;
                            var att = item.AttachmentFiles.Add(attInfo);
                            context.Load(att);
                            context.ExecuteQuery();
    
                           }
```

now if i try to open the attachment which get attached using the above code i will get this error:-

[image]

while if i manually attach the same file i can open the attachment without any issue.. any advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi SharePoint TestDev,

I tested your code in my SPO environment and am able to reproduce this error:

Open in desktop app:

[image]

Open in browser:

[image]

I Fixed it using below code:

- https://github.com/kongmengfei/sharedproject/blob/master/TeamifySharePointClassicSite/TeamifySharePointClassicSite/FileFormat.cs

Could you please have a try at your end?

BR

Comment: ok worked well..